# Change position of font-awesome icon in a button

Tags: font-awesome

I would like to have a button as follow:

```
[ Sign in with FB]
```

where FB is a font-awesome icon, which show up AFTER the text. Normally, if I call

```
<i class="icon-facebook">Sign in with</i>
```

then the FB icon will show up in front of the text.

Is it possible to achieve this effect using font-awesome (adding custom class etc.)?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using font-awesome with twitter-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the placement of font-awesome icons within most elements, but you may need to style your own buttons:

```
Sign in with <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
```

If you're using font-awesome with twitter-bootstrap, then can place the icons where you need to within a button class or other element:

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Sign in with <i class="icon-facebook"></i></button>
```

Or using the `icon-facebook-sign` icon (which is clearer) and `type="submit"`:

```
<button class="btn" type="submit">Sign in with <i class="icon-facebook-sign"></i></button>
```

Which produce the following respectively:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this. The problem is I won't have nice features of button_to, such as `:disable` option.

Comment: @nickhar is there anything wrong in using Font-Awesome with Twitter Bootstrap?

Comment: @PedroMoreira No, you can use together easily.